# Button on Wordpress customizer is not responding on click event

Tags: wordpress

I have custom button control for Wordpress customizer.I am trying to get click event but nothing happen after i click.

Button code:

```
<button type="button" id="Clickme" class="button customize-theme">Reset</button>
```

My .js flie

```
( function( $ ) {$(document).ready(function(){$("#Clickme").click(function({alert("I am clicked");});});} )( jQuery );
```

Actually i am trying to give alert with ok and cancel button.If user says ok then it will run below function.

```
function reset_mytheme_options() { 
remove_theme_mods();}
```

Answer (score 2):

The widgets in the customizer are dynamically added. You can use the DOMNodeInserted event to access these dynamically created elements.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( '#widgets-right' ).delegate( '#customize-theme-controls', 'DOMNodeInserted', function( ev ) {
        $( "#Clickme" ).click( function() {
            console.log("I am clicked");
        });
    }
});
```